# can I identify multiple series (lines) with values embedded in excel rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

This seems simple but I haven't been able to crack it yet.  I have a timeseries data set that looks something like:

```
Time  Val_1  Val_2
1.4     1      56
2.01    2      34
2.1     2      29
3.05    1      67
3.25    2      25
4       1      45
5.06    2      99
```

I need to do a "standard" time series plot where the X-axis is derived from the `Time` column.  But what I really need/want to do is to implicitly extract the data into multiple series, using a value in one of the other columns.  In this trivial example I have two series that I'd want to plot, and these are encoded in the `Val_1` column.  So here, I'd have a series for all `Val_1 =1` with three points, and a 4-point series with all the values where `Val_1 =2`.

I **could** manually re-arrange the data by somehow filtering/splitting/copying/pasting the different series values into yet another column, but that's a ton of extra work and these data sets in reality are pretty big and have waaaaay more series than I want to manually mangle.  ;-)

I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1114680/excel-creating-multiple-scatter-plots-from-one-table) but that requires a pivottable and some manipulation which I'd like to avoid if I can... maybe another way to phrase the question is "can I build a scatter plot where I **don't** have to build a separate column for each series that I want?

Comment: For an automated process with more control than a pivot table, use power query (data -> get and transform)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the short answer is no, you will need one column dedicated to each data series you want plotted.

The Excel Series function will accept one of the following (per argument)

- range of cells
- hard coded array of values
- named range

However, it won't accept a formula with calculations that would be required to include/exclude values (e.g. an IF function).  See John Peltier's great review of the [Series Function](https://peltiertech.com/chart-series-formula/) for more details about how it can be used.

If you want your series modified, you'll need helper columns.  The good news is that by converting your data to an [Excel Table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) (not necessarily a Pivot Table), you can minimize the amount of work necessary to accomplish your task.

The following table is probably as compact as you can get and still have the data formatted for the series you want.

[image: data table]

[image: chart]

Comment: OK, thanks.  Maybe it's just python and gnuplot to the rescue  :)

Comment: Excel VBA may work since you seem comfortable with programming.  R is another possible choice.  Good luck.